# Cookie send by Postman Native App doesn't set in browser

Tags: javascript, express, cookies, request, postman

I'm currently developing an express application and it uses cookie to authenticate user.

I use `res.cookie` method to create a cookie. But I can't set the cookie to the browser. Whenever I try to send a `POST` request with cookie in Postman Native App it doesn't set cookie in the browser. But the cookie is visible in Postman Native App.

I installed Postman Interceptor and Interceptor Bridge. But no result.

I tried to send the same `POST` request with Postman Chrome App. It works well and set's cookie in the browser.

Why Postman Native App can't set cookie in the browser? How to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, can you give us your code and a screen shot of your post man with the parameter and the header you sent please ?